# wxPython TaskbarIcon Menu Crash

Tags: python, wxpython, python-3.6

The following code is crashing when right-clicking on the system tray icon. It doesn't produce any error (except a complex error code that I cannot make sense of), so I'm having trouble tracking the issue down.

```
import wx
import wx.adv

class TaskbarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        super(TaskbarIcon, self).__init__()
        self.SetIcon(wx.Icon(wx.IconLocation("fav.ico")), "TestApp")
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnRunNow)

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        run_now_item = menu.Append(-1, "Run now...", "Run now.")
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        exit_item = menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.RunNow, run_now_item)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, exit_item)
        return menu

    def OnExit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
        self.frame.Close()

    def OnRunNow(self, event):
        self.ShowBalloon("Test", "Content", 5000)

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = wx.Frame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        TaskbarIcon(frame)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sunny chidi's answer lead me to the actual problem. There was some inconsistent naming going on with `RunNow` vs `OnRunNow`. Resolving this fixed it.

Comment: It's a bit churlish not to give at least a "Useful" upvote to sunny chidi's answer. It does resolve the naming issue, even if it is not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony trust me, I have considered accepting the answer and and giving him an upvote but chose not to because the code he posted contains deprecated functions, which I also mentioned in the comments. I am simply afraid people will take the code and copy paste.I'll give sunny an upvote on one of his other answers (none of which got an upvote so far, weirdly)

Comment: I've made a small edit to the answer, to avoid your concerns about the deprecated function. I have also replaced a function that is only available under Windows, that fails silently under others and might be misleading as well.

Comment: Fair enough, this edit is acceptable - allthough the recommended way is to just pass wx.ID_ANY (-1) to the `id` parameter, which lets wx pick a free ID.

Answer (score 2):

i think your problem lies with how you bind your events. try this

```
import wx.adv
import wx

# Note NewId has been deprecated since wx version 4.0.1 and replaced by wx.NewIdRef
ID_RUN = wx.NewIdRef()
ID_EXIT = wx.NewIdRef()


class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
        self.SetIcon(wx.Icon(wx.IconLocation("fav.ico")), "TestApp")
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.Append(ID_RUN, "Run now...")
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        menu.Append(ID_EXIT, "Exit")

        menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnRunNow, id=ID_RUN)

        menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=ID_EXIT)

        return menu


    def on_left_down(self, event):
        print ('Tray icon was left-clicked.')

    def OnRunNow(self, event):
        #Note: ShowBalloon is only available under Windows OS
        #self.ShowBalloon("Test", "Content", 5000)
        wx.MessageBox("Test", "Content")

    def OnExit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
        self.frame.Close()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=wx.Frame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        TaskBarIcon(frame)
        return True

def main():
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: wx.NewId() is actually deprecated now. Your solution lead me to the actual problem, a plain typo regarding `OnRunNow` and `RunNow`